# Como convertir fecha desde archivo XML

Tags: php, xml, date

Estoy obteniendo una fecha desde un archivo XML la cual se encuentra de la siguiente manera en el archivo `2019-05-13T16:02:16`.

Después de obtener esta fecha en una variable de PHP la guardo en una tabla en SQL, para darle un formato correcto a la fecha y que solo se almacene la fecha así sin hora, estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true );
$fechaCadena = strtotime("21/05/2021");
$fechaEntrada = getdate($fechaCadena);
$fechaEntrada = $xml['Fecha'];
```

Al revisar en la tabla la fecha me la guarda en el siguiente formato:

```
2019-05-13
```

Lo que quisiera es convertir esta fecha en el siguiente formato:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Intente anteriormente haciendo un `replace` cambiando los `'-'` por `'/'` pero aun así no funciono

```
$fechaCadena = strtotime(str_replace('-', '/',"21/05/2021"));
```

Quisiera que alguien me diera un poco mas de orientación en como convertir correctamente la fecha al formato que deseo.

Comment: En general, las bases de datos SQL guardan la fecha en un formato específico y, en caso de necesitar otro formato, se recomienda modificarlo al consultar. De cualquier forma, revisa [estas funciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#SetorGetSessionFormatFunctions) a ver si alguna te es útil.

Comment: @Triby Esto quiere decir que ya no dependo del formato al que lo quiero convertir en PHP si no al formato en como lo voy a insertar en la tabla de SQL ?

Comment: Efectivamente, guarda en base de datos con el formato por defecto y lo conviertes al leer. Te dejo este [otro enlace](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) con algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a trabajar con fechas **en el contexto de PHP**, te recomiendo que uses la clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Las ventajas son enormes, porque, entre otras cosas, `DateTime` te permitirá construir un objeto pasándole los datos en el constructor cuando la fecha tiene un formato válido (como es tu caso aquí), y cuando no, puedes usar `:createFromFormat` indicando en qué formato viene la fecha (por ejemplo, cuando hay formatos que no son la fecha en inglés).

Para construir una fecha a partir de valores con este formato: `2019-05-13T16:02:16`, basta con hacer esto:

```
$mDate=new DateTime('2019-05-13T16:02:16');
```

Y `$mDate` será un objeto `DateTime`:

```
var_dump($mDate);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-05-13 16:02:16.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

A partir de **ese objeto**, puedes hacer cualquier operación simple, como formatearlo:

Por ejemplo, el formato que necesitas:

```
echo $mDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Salida:**

```
2019-05-13
```

O cualquier otro:

```
echo $mDate->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
echo $mDate->format('d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;
echo $mDate->format('M').PHP_EOL;
echo $mDate->format('m-y-d').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
2019-05-13
13-05-2019
May
05-19-13
```

O cualquier operación compleja, como calcular intervalos, modificar, calcular ... En definitiva, aprovechar la bondad de los objetos. En el enlace, al inicio de la respuesta, podrás ver todas las posibilidades que te da la clase `DateTime`, la cual puedes usar en combinación con otras clases como `DateInterval` o `DatePeriod` para operaciones complejas.